# Is there any condition to detect only when browser close (x) is pressed in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using beforeunload function which works fine but it fires also if i press any  button or link in my page. what is the way to fire the event when only  the close (x) button is pressed?  My code:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'logout.php',
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        timeout: 4000
    });
});
```

Comment: no, you can't do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to detect these actions as of early 2016.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to differentiate 100% between close, refresh, form submission or link press. If you really need this, you can approximate a result based on:

- The position of the cursor. If it's in right corner on Mozilla or Chrome it would mean that the X is pressed. Left right corner for Safari, etc.
- Maybe add click events to all `<a>` html tags to set a FLAG to true.
- Same than above to other similar tags like `<form>` or others which could redirect the user to other website.
- Catch key press events to look for press of the key F5.

Even with all this, you can not be sure about it. If the use just closes the tab, or he click the reload button you could mistake, but at least gives you an approximation.

Comment: There are so many other ways a window can get closed that you cannot detect that any reasonable app cannot rely on these techniques and should find a different way to solve it's issue.  I can even close the window when it's minimized in Windows without even activating it.

Comment: I agree there is a lot of ways that can not be detected. If you read my comment the first and last thing I mention to him, it's that this can not be done with a 100% of reliability.

Comment: And, my point is that no design should count on getting notified of window closure because it cannot be made reliable.  As such, I find no reason to spend time coding all these things you suggest.  It makes much more sense to find a new way to solve the problem that does not rely on such a notification.  So, I find no value in your "approximation" answer.  It's not worth coding because it cannot be made reliable.  Who wants to implement a solution that works only sometimes?

Comment: 1- You do not know the purpose of the website.

Comment: Uhhh, the purpose of this site is to offer "good" or "best" solutions to the problems the OP has.  I'm entitled to my opinion and I don't think your answer provides a "good" solution and I explained why.  If you check my history, you'll see I know a bit about how this site works.  The real answer to this question is that it can't be done in any reliable or comprehensive way so the app should find a different way to solve their issue than trying to bank on unreliable information.

Comment: So, you just do things 100% reliable or not do it, that is your point of view. Mine is not that, even if it is not possible do something 100% reliable I try to look for other approaches which could "work" although they are not 100% reliable and then validate if it compensate or not depending mostly in my needs, it is not the same code for a company than do it for your own server where only you will be accessing... the needs are different and that what I am defending...

Comment: Yes, I find a solution that will be 100% reliable and predictable, even if it means changing the design.  Anything less makes buggy, unreliable software.

Comment: Not always exists a 100% reliable solution, not even changing the design.